# Same wildcard SSL certificate with different organizations

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, wildcard, csr

I'm working in a company that has recently bought daughter company. Migration procedures are happening and I was asked this:

We already have purchased a wildcard SSL certificate on let's say *.someurl.com and in CSR we entered our current company's name.

Now someone who is responsible for migration came to me and asked to get a new wildcard certificate for the same URL (*.someurl.com) but in CSR there should be the company's name that we recently bought and they should work parallel to each other.

I can't find any info on this on google, so I'm asking here. Is it possible to do so?

For CA, we're using thawte.

Thanks!

Comment: DV or OV certificate? If it is a DV one, what is written in the Organization part of the CSR is not used and is not even in the final certificate. Because DV certificate authentify only an hostname, not an organization name. Look at your current certificate (not CSR) and see if any organization is there or not (I guess not, because I think you have only DV certificate(s) hence the Organization in the CSR is irrelevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to create a new certificate for the same domain but with a different organization. Of course, you still need to prove that you actual own the domain the certificate is for but this should not be a problem in your case.

What is not possible is to just modify the certificate or the CSR because this would invalidate the signature. Instead a new CSR with the new information need to be created and be submitted to the CA for signing. The private key from the previous certificate could in theory be reused. But unless there is public key pinning done against this certificate I see no advantage in this.